# Feeds's opening message in an auto-generated chat room leads to a page with comment links that won't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, comments, chat, onebox

1. Have a conversation going in comments on an answer (whoops)
2. SE asks you to migrate to chat.
3. Accept.
4. Chat opens.
5. First line is from Feeds, with a oneboxed link to the answer. It's like this:
   `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/<question-id>/<title-ish>/<answer-id>#<answer-id>`
6. Click on it.
7. Now observe *any* comment link (the linkified comment timestamps) on the page. The trailing `/<answer-id>` is still there.
8. Paste any such link in a chat room.
9. The link fails to onebox.

It's not a *huge* deal, but it is kind of bewildering when you expect comment oneboxing to work and, because you're a software developer, can't help but spend (it turns out, *waste*!) five minutes of your precious life trying to figure out why. :P

I guess there are a few ways to fix this, including making the comment link oneboxing itself more lenient, or removing that trailing `/<answer-id>` from the comment links.

But, assuming the URL's anchor works, can we just drop the `<answer-id>` from Feeds' one-boxed URL?

Comment: I'd simplify to "certain spellings of comment links don't onebox in chat"? It's nice of course to demonstrate that there is a _sane_ [sic] path to get in such a situation too :)

Comment: @sehe: I'd be happy to accept that alternative title _if_ this goes the way of fixing the comment oneboxing. It may be that the Feeds link changes, or the comment links change.

Comment: I think the onebox detection code should become less picky. That's probably the whole problem. After all, the links _do_ work

Comment: Besides, I already have a bug or two open about "certain spellings of <X> don't onebox in chat", for different <X>, so :P